# C# Linq to SQL: How to express "CONVERT([...] AS INT)"?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In MSSQL you can convert a string into an integer like this:

```
CONVERT(INT, table.column)
```

Is there any C# expression that Linq to SQL would translate to this?

In C# you can normally do the same by using `int.Parse()`, but unfortunately, trying to use `int.Parse()` in a Linq query results in an error:

> Method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Is there any C# expression that Linq to SQL would translate to `CONVERT(INT, ...)`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

C# has [`Convert.ToInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) which should do what you're looking for.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 11):

[Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx) should work.  Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) for information on the translations.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

for LINQ to entities, if it is simply a mismatch between your model and the DB you can overcome this using a valueconverter with EF Core.

```
public OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Entity<mymodel>()
              .Property(e => e.myModelIntColumn) // this column is a string in the db
              .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<int?, string>(m => m.HasValue ? m.ToString().Substring(0,10) : null, db => int.Parse(db ?? "0")));
}
```

and in my LINQ i can then use bit comparison:

```
MyDBSet.Where( e => (BitsWanted == 0 ||  ( e.myModelIntColumn & BitsWanted ) > 0));
```