# How do I query a VARCHAR as an integer

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a column that holds VARCHARs and I have a flag that determines if the value is a string or integer. I would like perform a search on the integers but they are stored as VARCHAR. How do I do this?

I am trying to do this in a where clause.

```
var q = from x in context.table
        where x.Criteria > 0
        select new
        {
              x
        }
```

Comment: having "a flag that determines if the value is a string or integer" like that often indicates there is a problem with your design...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: No, not really.

Comment: @Timwi: Yes, really (if you are using a single column/field to store different types).

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: OMG, how could I be so wrong. Your astute argumentation is utterly convincing!

Comment: Perhaps he's emulating the Windows Registry, which needs `INTEGER`, `TEXT`, and `BLOB` values in the same column.

Comment: @Timwi: that's a strange tone to take. If you are storing different types in a column, it is 'often' (note the word 'often') an indication that the design is not quite right.

Comment: @dan04: the mention of 'VARCHARs ' would suggest he is not enumerating the registry...plus the tag of "SQl Server 2008"

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: The relational nature of SQL databases imposes limitations on the structure the data can have, including for example the conspicuous absence of polymorphism. There are numerous real-life business use-cases that mandate a minimum of type variability within collections of otherwise related entities and/or a minimum of run-time (post-implementation) customisability. A significant proportion of such use-cases do not map trivially to relational database tables, necessitating a model, e.g. the key/value pair pattern, in which values need to be of different types within the same column.

Comment: @Timwi: I'm aware of those facts, thanks. If "A significant proportion of such use-cases do not map trivially to relational database tables" then don't use a relational database.

Comment: If you are using key value tables, likely you have a very bad design from both a performance and maintenance perspecitve.

Answer (score 1):

`CAST(TheColumn AS INTEGER)`

Comment: how would I do this in a where clause using linq

Answer (score 1):

### sql

```
select isnull(Convert(int, varcharColumn),0)
from atable
where isInteger = 1
```

### linq

```
var q = context.YourCustomView;
```

Comment: how would I do this in a where clause using linq

Comment: var q = context.YourTable.Where(i=> i.IsNumber).Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.VarcharColumn));

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to pull down the values from the server as strings and do the conversion in LINQ to Objects.

```
var q = context.table
    .Where(x => x.Criteria > 0)
    .Select(x => x.IntOrStringValue)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(v => Convert.ToInt32(v));
```

replace `x.Criteria > 0` with your logic that indicates the value is an integer.
replace `x.IntOrStringValue` with your column containing the integers.

Comment: [Linq-to-SQL can translate `Convert.ToInt32()` just fine.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992189/)

Comment: The question is tagged linq-to-entities, not linq-to-sql.