# I need help finding a record in an Entity Framework context using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework context with an object called "LengthDatas" and a property/column called "AbsoluteCounter" that is a string value.  The string value represents a decimal number.  I would like to use a lambda expression to find the largest one.  How would I modify my expression to achieve this ?

context.LengthDatas.Where(c => c.AbsoluteCounter.Last())

(I know the column should be decimal and I will convert this over to a decimal value at a later time)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `OrderByDescending` and `First(OrDefault)` combination:

```
context.LengthDatas.OrderByDescending(c => c.AbsoluteCounter).FirstOrDefault();
```

But to really get decimal comparison (not string) you have to define your own method, as described in an answer to *[Convert string to decimal in group join linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216043/convert-string-to-decimal-in-group-join-linq-query)* question.

Comment: It's important the conversion to decimal is done first. Ordering strings doesn't ensure the largest number(or even string) will be the first one.

Comment: How did you get Decimal.Parse(c.AbsoluteCounter) to work with Linq to Entities?

Comment: I'm getting this error message: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: Check out that answer: [Convert string to decimal in group join linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216043/convert-string-to-decimal-in-group-join-linq-query)

Comment: Very nice, I'll give that a try. You should have referenced it in you answer above.

Comment: Is there an equivalent when using code first? I don't actually have an EDMX.

Answer (score 2):

You should do **it first (switch to decimal)** , then you can easily change your query to be :

```
context.LengthDatas.OrderByDescending(c => c.AbsoluteCounter))
```

If absolutecounter is decimal then the query will order it and the first element will be the largest

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by string can fail if the data is malformed (leading spaces, alphas). If you can afford to bring the data into memory, this should cut out the loopholes:

```
        var result = db.LengthDatas
            .ToList()
            .Select(c =>
            {
                decimal d;
                Decimal.TryParse(c.AbsoluteCounter, out d);
                return d;
            })
            .Max();
```

But if you're confident about the data quality, just use

```
        var result1 = db.LengthDatas.Max(c => c.AbsoluteCounter);
```

**ADDENDUM**

To round out the discussion about converting the string to decimal on the server instead of in memory, I tried out the technique @MarcinJuraszek references above.

I'm testing in a Code First app, but added an EDMX by adding an ADO.Net Entity Data Model to the project. There's a few things to tidy up, but essentially the following type of query will work

```
var result = db.LengthDatas.Max(c => EdmxExtensions.DecimalParse(c.AbsoluteCounter));
```

The SQL generated by Linq to Entities is

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    MAX( CAST( [Extent1].[AbsoluteCounter] AS decimal(12,2))) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[LengthDatas] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

However, should note that this is not a robust conversion as you get with c# Decimal.TryParse. It will throw an exception with malformed strings.