# Convert to int inside LINQ statement possible?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am wanting to save a record in a database using a simple LINQ statement. I am finding it is not possible to use a `Convert.ToInt32` inside the linq statement like below:

```
using (var context = new Stc.LeadTracker.DataModel.Models.DBNameContext())
{
    var newLead = new DataModel.Models.LeadRequest();
    newLead.FormId = Convert.ToInt32(formId);
    newLead.Request = queryString;
    newLead.Success = true;
    newLead.RetryCount = 0;
    newLead.CreatedBy = nvCollection["iw"];
    newLead.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    context.LeadRequests.Add(newLead);
    context.SaveChanges();
    leadId = newLead.LeadRequestId;
}
```

I can certainly do the conversion before the LINQ statement, was curious to know if that is my only option.

Comment: This is not LINQ

Comment: I think this question has already been addressed here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992189/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-how-to-express-convert-as-int

Comment: Why? What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks he is just curious wanting to know if there is another way to cast a value to int in `LINQ to SQL` beside `Convert.ToInt32(...)`.

Comment: after doing some more testing. It is possible to use the Convert statement as the example is listed.

Comment: @JonHarding: Maybe it was not supported until lately. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7703a50-726a-4017-b682-99b7f9b6caa9/how-to-convert-a-string-value-to-an-int-value-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 0):

I would Convert.ToInt32(formId) before you get to the using statement.

Linq does not like Convert statements depending on the ORM

Check this out
[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: Read the question more carefully: "I can certainly do the conversion before the LINQ statement, was curious to know if that is my only option."

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using int.Parse() or int.TryParse()?  Also, why are you not able to use Convert.ToInt32()?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, `Convert.ToInt32()` can be used OK. He just wants to know if there is another way to do it. `int.Parse` will also do it if the `formId` is string.

Comment: Ok.  Anyways, Convert.ToInt32() works only for 32-bit ints. I think he should try using int.Parse() or int.TryParse() for safer conversions.

Comment: We also have `Convert.ToInt64()` and `int.Parse` is in fact `Int32.Parse`.

Comment: @Siva, `int.Parse` and `int.TryParse` only work on "32-bit int"

Answer (score -1):

You can cast the variable like this:
(int)formid

You have to check if "formId" can be casted to int.

```
using (var context = new Stc.LeadTracker.DataModel.Models.DBNameContext())
{
    var newLead = new DataModel.Models.LeadRequest();
    newLead.FormId = (int)formId;
    newLead.Request = queryString;
    newLead.Success = true;
    newLead.RetryCount = 0;
    newLead.CreatedBy = nvCollection["iw"];
    newLead.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    context.LeadRequests.Add(newLead);
    context.SaveChanges();
    leadId = newLead.LeadRequestId;
}
```

There is a similar question here:
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210526/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth)