# Compare varchar to int in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to find all entries that have a `SALARIO` greater than 10,000. The `SALARIO` column in my SQL Server table is of type `varchar` and the query I'm trying to write goes like this

```
from e in db.ASALARIADOS 
where int.Parse(e.SALARIO) > 10000 
select e;
```

But I get a not supported exception. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Linq to SQL: How to express "CONVERT(\[...\] AS INT)"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992189/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-how-to-express-convert-as-int)

Comment: What is the type variable to store the result of your linq query?

Comment: i'm storing that query with a `var`

Comment: I tested your query but instead of a varchar I have a bool and it worked. In .net you don't have the varchar, you will have a string. Are you sure the exception is thrown in that code?

Comment: The **real** solution would be to use the **most appropriate** datatype - in the database, to begin with! So if this is a salary (a numeric value) - ***why on earth*** is it stored as `varchar`?!?!?!? Fix this, make it a `DECIMAL(20,4)` or whatever makes sense to you - then all your problems with this go away automagically .....

Answer (score 1):

```
from e in db.ASALARIADOS 
where Convert.ToInt32(e.SALARIO) > 10000 
select e;
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me, i get this message `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @DelGiudice I used `ToInt32`

Comment: @Hogan You cannot use Convert.ToInt32 or any Convert.To... inside a linq query, it will always return an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this because in the end, this is converted to a SQL query and it cannot translate your int.Parse to SQL.

What you can try however, is this.

Create a small function that will return true or false depending on whether the value passed in is more than 10000.

```
    public bool salarioCheck(string salario)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(salario) > 10000)
        { return true; }
        return false;
    }

    public void yourMethod()
    {
        from e in db.ASALARIADOS 
        where salarioCheck(e)
        select e;
    }
```

So you are basically doing your conversion inside salarioCheck().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I haven't tested it but I remember using "let" clause and Int32.Parse inside Linq to accomplish something similar in the past.

```
from e in db.ASALARIADOS 
let x = Int32.Parse(e.SALAIO.Trim()) 
where x > 10000 
select e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a workaround: haven't tried this one yet but this should work

```
db.ASALARIADOS.toList().Where(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.SALARIO) > 10000)
```