# Opertor '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'string' on where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

While executing below linq query on controller, I got this error:

> Opertor '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'string'

Controller:

```
from t in db.ASN_ITEM
    join t0 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t0.ITEM_CODE        
    where
         t.REGION_ID == RegionId && 
         (Status == "" || Status == "-1" || t.SCAN_STAT == Status)
```

Here type of `t.SCAN_STAT` is `int?` and type of variable `status` is `string`.

I have tried this one:

```
(Status == "" || Status == "-1" || SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.SCAN_STAT) == Status)
```

But not fetching the desired data based on the condition.

When I tried `(Status == "" || Status == "-1" || t.SCAN_STAT.ToString() == Status)`, I got this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

These are the solutions I got from other sites.
Now how can I solve this error?

Comment: How about `t.SCAN_STAT.Value.ToString() == Status`?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992189/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-how-to-express-convert-as-int   You may go the other way round with this solution however, i.e., convert status to int and check.

Comment: You just want `Status == -1`. Notice the lack of quotes?

Comment: If `Status`variable can contain only int values (or null value), consider declaring it as `int?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert Status to int before linq query, then use it in the query as int:

```
var intStatus = (int)null;
int.TryParse(Status,out intStatus);

from t in db.ASN_ITEM
    join t0 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t0.ITEM_CODE        
    where
         t.REGION_ID == RegionId && 
         (intStatus == null || intStatus == -1 || t.SCAN_STAT == intStatus;
```

Comment: @LimnaD'silva but you should do this outside the linq query. It's impossible you get this error if you di before

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you use `EntityFramework`, it will try to convert the `System.String ToString()` method to a SQL and it fails to do that as it cannot convert to SQL statement/ 'store expression'.

You should just move the `ToString()` method out of store expression. For this, You can first execute the EF expression using ToList() or ToEumerable() method. Then use your condition on that `(Status == "" || Status == "-1" || t.SCAN_STAT == Status)'`

Or you can try this also :

```
from t in db.ASN_ITEM
join t0 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t0.ITEM_CODE        
let SCAN_STAT = t.SCAN_STAT.ToString()
where
     t.REGION_ID == RegionId && 
     (Status == "" || Status == "-1" || SCAN_STAT == Status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider of making intermediate variable for checking by using LINQ `let`:

```
from t in db.ASN_ITEM
join t0 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t0.ITEM_CODE        
let test = t.SCAN_STAT.ToString()
where
     t.REGION_ID == RegionId && 
     (Status == "" || Status == "-1" || test == Status)
```

This way, you could compare `string` to `string`

Note: beware of the `string` format for each though. If needed be, you could even ensure that they have the same format, for instance:

```
from t in db.ASN_ITEM
join t0 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t0.ITEM_CODE        
let test = t.SCAN_STAT.ToString().ToUpper().Trim()
let test2 = Status.ToUpper().Trim()
where
     t.REGION_ID == RegionId && 
     (Status == "" || Status == "-1" || test == test2)
```

Alternatively, you could also do the reverse:

```
int? test = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Status) ? null : Convert.ToInt32(Status); //or, adjust the null as you wish
```

Then use it like this:

```
from t in db.ASN_ITEM
join t0 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t0.ITEM_CODE        
where
     t.REGION_ID == RegionId && 
     (Status == "" || Status == "-1" || t.SCAN_STAT == test)
```

This way, you compare `int?` with `int?`

Comment: Linq to entities won't recognize ToString function

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value in your `int?`. To do this you need to use `.Value` but before you need to check if `t.SCAN_STAT` has value to prevent argument null exception:

```
(Status == "" || Status == "-1" || (t.SCAN_STAT.HasValue && t.SCAN_STAT.Value.ToString() == Status))
```